# How to use insertion sort on doubly linked list C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm working on a project that requires me to sort a linked list using insertion sort, in the most efficient way. I wrote an algorithm that worked but it wasn't the most efficient - it compared values from the beginning of the list instead of going backward. Now, I have an algorithm that compares values going backward, but it doesn't work. The debugger shows that current->prev is a nullptr so it won't run the function. I have it initialized and when I do cout << current->prev it prints the value. I looked at other posts on this topic but I can't find what's wrong with that line of my code. Here's the header file that contains the function in the linked list class:

```
#include<iostream>

class LinkedList
{
private:
struct ListNode
{
    double value;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode *prev;
    ListNode(double val, ListNode* nextPtr = nullptr, ListNode* prevPtr = 
nullptr) :
        value(val), next(nextPtr), prev(prevPtr) {}
};
ListNode *head;

public:
LinkedList()
{ 
    head = nullptr; 
}

~LinkedList() 
{
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        ListNode *current = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete current;
    }
}
void insert(double val)
{
    if (!head)
        head = new ListNode(val);
    else
    {
        ListNode *temp = new ListNode(val);
        temp->next = head;
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
}

void display()
{
    ListNode *temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
    std::cout << temp->value << " ";
    temp = temp->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void insertSort()
{
    ListNode *marker, *current;

    for (marker = head->next; marker != nullptr; marker = marker->next)
    {
        double temp = marker->value;                                 
        current = marker;   

        // this line throws the exception: read access violation.
        // current->prev was nullptr.                                       
        while (current != nullptr && current->prev->value >= temp) 
        {
            current->value = current->prev->value;            
            current = current->prev;                       
        }
        current->value = temp;                  
      }  
   }
};
```

Here's the source file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   LinkedList list;

   list.insert(23);
   list.insert(54);
   list.insert(2);
   list.insert(8);
   list.insert(3.2);
   list.insert(14);
   list.insert(43);
   list.insert(0);
   list.insert(9);
   list.insert(2);

   cout << "Contents of linked list before insert sort:\n";
   list.display();


   list.insertSort();

   cout << "Contents of linked list after insert sort:\n";
   list.display();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider:  What's `current->prev` when `current == head`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I've considered that, but `current` never equals `head`, since `current = marker` and `marker = head->next`. In the for loop, `marker` is incremented so it's never equal to `head`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm is correct I think. In your inner loop `current` goes backwards. At some point it will be `head` which means `current->prev` is NULL.

Comment: @MFisherKDX and @1201ProgramAlarm you're right, the inner loops runs `while (current != nullptr)` so I just changed that to `while (current->prev != nullptr)` and now it works. Thanks for helping. Such a simple oversight must mean it's time for bed.

Comment: Just a comment here - why is scanning the list backwards from the end more efficient than scanning the list forwards from the beginning? With either approach, the average number of nodes compared is n/2.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's more efficient since that sublist is always in order, so if the element being compared is greater than the last element in the sorted sublist, it wouldn't need to go through every element from the head - it can just be compared with that last element and placed at the end there. I'm still trying to understand how to analyze the algorithm's efficiency using Big O, but the code seems to go through fewer comparisons this way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix this. The inner loop ran `while (current != nullptr)` so when current was at head and it was assigned `current->prev` it was pointing to nullptr. I changed the while loop condition to `current->prev != nullptr` and now it runs properly since it's never pointing to nullptr.